# Python Tornado's web.RequestHandler.set_status() with a reason string seems to be ignored

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using Tornado to implement a simple ReST web service. When responding with error codes I would like to customize the reason string. I'm trying to use web.RequestHandler.set_status() for this, by specifying a reason string.

My logging shows that _reason is set to the string I specified, but that is not what is returned once self.finish() is called. I'm not sure why.

Help appreciated.

My send_error_with_code helper function:

```
def send_error_with_code(self, status_code, err, allow=[]):
    log.info("in send_error_with_code: %s:%s", status_code, str(err))
    self.set_status(status_code, reason=str(err))
    log.info("self._reason is %s", self._reason)
    if status_code == 500:
        log.exception(str(err))
    else:
        log.error(str(err))
    if allow:
        self.set_header('Allow', ', '.join(allow))
    self.finish()
```

It's called from an exception handler, before returning any other output to the client.

Comment: Can you show your code? Or at least a representative example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I added my helper method that's calling set_status()

Comment: I took your method, removed the log.* calls, and tried it calling it a "hello, world" scenario on my machine, and it works fine. If I use `curl -v` to query Tornado, I can see my custom reason being returned in the header. What client are you using to determine if your reason code is set?

Comment: A simple python one using httplib, but I also checked the response using wireshark, and the response is indeed the canned one. I'm currently stuck with Tornado 3.1.1, hoping to push an upgrade in my organization soon.

Comment: Looking at the tornado 3.1.1 source, it looks like the only place _reason is used is in write_error, which isn't called if you just call finish() after set_status(). If you call send_error(), _reason is cleared.

Comment: I'm using Tornado 3.1.1 on my machine as well. I'll add an answer that shows my working example.

Comment: *sigh* Found it. I completely forgot that the request is passing through a "helpful" proxy that is obscuring the custom response string.

Comment: :) Fun stuff. Good luck fixing that!